# How does the Range.Value vba property reads cells with formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am sometimes using VBA to manipulate data and was wondering, would anyone know,in the case of cells whose value is defined by formula, if the Range.Value property will read a value saved in memory (result of the formula) or will instead run the formula again ? I thought of it as a way to improve my codes but cannot find the information

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`Range.Value` does not recalculate the formula.

This is easily testable with a setup like the following. In a cell, enter a formula like `=A1+A2`, then turn off automatic calculation. Then change the values in `A1` and `A2`.

[image]

In the immediate window, `? ActiveCell.Value` returns `0`, which, well, makes sense.

[image]

Comment: I was writing a whole sub to show this, and you just do it easily.